# ASP.Net Integrated Pipeline and HTTPResponseBase.Headers

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

Ok...

I'm writing a ASP.Net MVC 2 application, and one of the requirements is that I log the headers on the requests we receive, and also on the responses we send...

My approach to do this has been to create a controller that overrides OnActionExecuting and OnActionExecuted, and then create our actual "live" controllers by inheriting from this rather than from the usual base class. This way, I basically get the logging functionality for free.

While this approach works fine for handling the requests, responses seem to be another matter. I am getting an error telling me that the Headers property of the HTTPResponseBase class requires IIS to be using the Integrated Pipeline. I therefore have two questions.

**Question 1.**

Can anyone suggest a means to get the headers through a means other than HTTPResponseBase.Headers? I have considered for example simply parsing the entire resposne and getting them that way myself, but I was hoping someone might have a better way...

**Question 2.**

What is this Integrated Pipeline? What does it do? How do I enable it?

Cheers in anticipation...

Martin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In response to Question 2:

Integrated Pipeline is a new feature in IIS 7 and higher, you can change the application pool in IIS7 to use this new pipeline.

Comment: +1 Any idea how I would do that? And can it be done with the Visual Studio Development server?

Comment: You can't do it with Visual Studio Development server, but you can with IIS Express which you can get using the Web Platform Installer.

Comment: You may have to make changes to your web.config file too. I recommend reading this MSDN article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb515251.aspx